# A Very Simple Support Vector Machine with SMO Algorithm Implementation

Tags: python, mathematics, machine-learning

**Context.** I was looking for some simple implementation of SVM with the SMO algorithm that can be used as an in-class problem together with a simple mathematical explanation of how it works.
The problem is, that even simplest modifications of SMO I was able to find, e.g. [Simplified SMO from Stanford CS course](http://cs229.stanford.edu/materials/smo.pdf), are still complicated enough.
Moreover, mathematical formulas behind it, e.g. [this random notes on the internet](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e176/lectures/ch9/node9.html), are lengthy and it's easy to make an error during derivation.
At the end of the day I decided to write my own implementation with my own formulas.

**What help am I seeking for.**
Since this implementation was made from scratch with formulas derived from scratch I'm not sure if I didn't break SMO during all the simplifications.
Or maybe there are some problems with all this derivation/implementation I just don't see.
I have no one to ask for review, so I will highly appreciate any critical remarks/comments from community.

- I have posted implementation with some tests on [GitHub](https://github.com/fbeilstein/simplest_smo_ever), implementation of bare SVM (contains approximately 30 lines of code) provided below

```py
class SVM:
  def __init__(self, kernel='linear', C=10000.0, max_iter=100000, degree=3, gamma=1):
    self.kernel = {'poly'  : lambda x,y: np.dot(x, y.T)**degree,
                   'rbf'   : lambda x,y: np.exp(-gamma*np.sum((y - x[:,np.newaxis])**2, axis=-1)),
                   'linear': lambda x,y: np.dot(x, y.T)}[kernel]
    self.C = C
    self.max_iter = max_iter

  def restrict_to_square(self, t, v0, u):
    t = (np.clip(v0 + t*u, 0, self.C) - v0)[1]/u[1]
    return (np.clip(v0 + t*u, 0, self.C) - v0)[0]/u[0]

  def fit(self, X, y):
    self.X = X.copy()
    self.y = y * 2 - 1
    self.lambdas = np.zeros_like(self.y, dtype=float)
    self.K = self.kernel(self.X, self.X) * self.y[:,np.newaxis] * self.y
    
    for _ in range(self.max_iter):
      for idxM in range(len(self.lambdas)):
        idxL = np.random.randint(0, len(self.lambdas))
        Q = self.K[[[idxM, idxM], [idxL, idxL]], [[idxM, idxL], [idxM, idxL]]]
        v0 = self.lambdas[[idxM, idxL]]
        k0 = 1 - np.sum(self.lambdas * self.K[[idxM, idxL]], axis=1)
        u = np.array([-self.y[idxL], self.y[idxM]])
        t_max = np.dot(k0, u) / (np.dot(np.dot(Q, u), u) + 1E-15)
        self.lambdas[[idxM, idxL]] = v0 + u * self.restrict_to_square(t_max, v0, u)
    
    idx, = np.nonzero(self.lambdas > 1E-15)
    self.b = np.sum((1.0 - np.sum(self.K[idx] * self.lambdas, axis=1)) * self.y[idx]) / len(idx)
  
  def decision_function(self, X):
    return np.sum(self.kernel(X, self.X) * self.y * self.lambdas, axis=1) + self.b
```

- It seemingly works at least in simple cases, though I didn't test it extensively
  [image]
- My mathematical notes can be found on [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344460740_Yet_more_simple_SMO_algorithm). They contain a detailed explanation, though fitting under two pages. The key idea is writing the dual problem Lagrangian as
  $$
  \mathscr{L}^* =\boldsymbol{k}^T_0 \boldsymbol{v}_0 + \frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{v}^{\,T}_0 \, \boldsymbol{Q} \, \boldsymbol{v}_0 + \text{Const},
  $$
  where
  $$
  \begin{align}
  \boldsymbol{v}_0 &= (\lambda_{\color{red}M}, \lambda_{\color{blue}L})^T,\\ \boldsymbol{k}_0 &= \left(1 - \boldsymbol{\lambda}^T\boldsymbol{K}_{{\color{red}M}}, 1 - \boldsymbol{\lambda}^T\boldsymbol{K}_{{\color{blue}L}}\right)^T,\\ \boldsymbol{Q} &=
  \begin{pmatrix} K_{{\color{red}M},{\color{red}M}} & K_{{\color{red}M},{\color{blue}L}} \\  K_{{\color{blue}L},{\color{red}M}} & K_{{\color{blue}L},{\color{blue}L}} \\ \end{pmatrix}.
  \end{align}
  $$

\$\lambda_{\color{red}M}\$ and \$\lambda_{\color{blue}L}\$ are dual variables we aim to minimize at current iteration of SMO, \$\boldsymbol{K}\$ is the matrix that comprises information on kernel function \$K\$ of all possible pairs of datapoints \$\boldsymbol{x}_i\$ and their classes \$y_i = \pm 1\$
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{K} = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 y_1 K(\boldsymbol{x}_1; \boldsymbol{x}_1) & \dots & y_1 y_N K(\boldsymbol{x}_1; \boldsymbol{x}_N) \\ \cdots & \cdots & \cdots                                                                                                                                    \\ y_N y_1 K(\boldsymbol{x}_N; \boldsymbol{x}_1) & \dots & y_N y_N K(\boldsymbol{x}_N; \boldsymbol{x}_N) \\ \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
One index at \$\boldsymbol{K}\$ means corresponding vector-column, two indices -- single element.
Then I represent all possible new lambdas as \$\boldsymbol{v}(t) =\boldsymbol{v}_0 + t \boldsymbol{u}\$, where \$   \boldsymbol{u} = (-y_{\color{blue}L}, y_{\color{red}M})^T\$.
Value of \$t\$ that maximizes Lagrangian can be found as
\begin{equation}
 t_* = \frac{\boldsymbol{k}^T_0 \boldsymbol{u}}{\boldsymbol{u}^{\,T} \boldsymbol{Q} \boldsymbol{u}}.
\end{equation}
I restrict it so that lambdas fit the rectangle and do update
\begin{equation}
 (\lambda_{\color{red}M}^\text{new}, \lambda_{\color{blue}L}^\text{new})^T = \vec{v}_0 + t_*^{\text{restr}} \vec{u}.
\end{equation}

- I will highly appreciate any critique/reviews/suggestions.

Comment: For a review of your formulas, a better place to ask is https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @G.Sliepen , I'm more concerned about general idea/algorithm than equations. Presumably, errors in formulas would have been manifested during implementation/testing. I'm seeking for someone more experienced in SVM and SMO than I am for a feedback if this is a valid modification of SMO. I would like to use this code as an in-class problem, but I'm afraid to mislead my students.